# What ways are there of separating long running tasks in EF and Web API in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am submitting data to a web api. I then have to run a machine learning algorithm that uses all the data submitted and finds the best parameters based on sweeping. However, there is no reason that the user has to wait for this process to finish and I would like my web api method to return while the backend web api is stil running. Does async do that? Or maybe Task.Run? I am relatively new to the wonderful world of C#.

Comment: Do you want just start running algorithm, without returning any result data back to the user?

Comment: Yes the results of the long running tasks is irrelevant to the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say how long the long running task will take.  But it's not a good idea to have a long running process run in the background of a Web API. Most web servers assume the task will take a short time and can restart app domains etc any time they want.

If the task is < 90 seconds then you could consider using 
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem

This will hold off any kind of app domain restart for 90 seconds.

Or if the tasks takes longer then use some kind of queuing method, perhaps a windows service or [HangFire](http://hangfire.io/).  I've used Hangfire for long running processes with [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to update the user of the status of the process and it's worked pretty well.

Comment: Wow I did not know about hangfire but that seems to be perfect for my particular demands!

Comment: Does hangFire work well with EF databases? For example I am trying to do some pre processing, run an artificial neural network sweep, and save the resultant weights and parameters to a database. Does running BackgroundJob.Enqueue lose the context of that particular web api?

Comment: I've used Dapper to save information to the database, I tend to avoid EF when possible, sorry not sure how well HangFire works with EF.